# How to add playbook permissions in azure sentinel via terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sentinel

I have terraformized Log Analytics Workspace, Sentinel by using below code:

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log_analytics_workspace" {
  name                = "log-test-permissions"
  location            = "xxx"
  resource_group_name = "xxx"
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 90
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "sentinel" {
  solution_name         = "SecurityInsights"
  location              = "xxx"
  resource_group_name   = "xxx"
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics_workspace.id
  workspace_name        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics_workspace.name

  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/SecurityInsights"
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics_workspace]

}
```

I'm planning to terraformize the playbook permissions configuration by following below steps.

1. Go to Azure Sentinel -> Configuration -> Settings -> Playbook permissions -> Configure Permissions
2. Check 'Current permissions' tab to see if the resource group containing the playbook is listed. Else select the required resource groups in 'Browse' tab and select 'Apply'.

[image]

Can anyone please help me out regarding how can we terraformize the playbook permissions on sentinel for a specific resourcegroup ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code :

```
 terraform {
      backend "azurerm" {
        resource_group_name  = "XXX"
        storage_account_name = "remteccc1"
        container_name       = "terraform"
        key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
      }
  }


resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "exm" {
  name                = "dsd"
 location                    = xx
  resource_group_name         = xxx
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 90
}


resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "log_analytics_solution_sentinel" {
  solution_name         = "SecurityInsights"
 location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace. exm.id
  workspace_name        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace. exm.name
  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/SecurityInsights"
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.rgcore-management-la]

}
```

The  permissions to playbook can be given is as follows.

***You need to have Permissions to playbook for which we can add roles like Microsoft Sentinel Automation Contributor role to the resource which allows the access on sentinel***.

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sentinel_contributor" {
  scope              = "/subscriptions/<subId>/resourceGroups/<rg>"
 // role_definition_id = azurerm_role_definition.sentinelcontributor.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Sentinel Contributor"
  principal_id       =  "3367a746-xxx18686"#objectid of azure security insights app objectId or servicepincipal 
data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}
```

These roles are to be assigned to the security insights  or resource group that contains the Microsoft Sentinel workspace.

[image]

With the permissions , automation rule is created and is reflected in portal under microsoft Sentinel.

```
resource "azurerm_sentinel_automation_rule" "example" {
  name                       = "56094f72-ac3f-40e7-a0c0-47bd95f70336"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.rgcore-management-la.id
  display_name               = "automation_rule1"
  order                      = 1
  action_incident {
    order  = 1
    status = "Active"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Kavya... by using Sentinel Automation Contributor role , can we run playbook automatically ?

Comment: Hi Kavya .. have done the similar changes. Able to create Sentinel Automation Contributor on securityInsights on resource group level on serviceprincipal. But I could not create the automation rule. Facing the below issue : [BadRequest] : Caller is missing required playbook triggering permissions on playbook resource '/subscriptions/359ca389-01e3-4f49-813a-a0afe3c68e40/resourceGroups/tie0-cl040-tst-t0/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/Send-email-with-formatted-incident-report', or Microsoft Sentinel is missing required permissions to verify the caller has permissions

Comment: Able to create automation rule by changing the severity. But not able to create automation rule to trigger playbook

Comment: try to create another role assignment ,  make  the scope to ID of your playbook resource, and principal_id to the service principal /user trying with ` Contributor` role.

Comment: Hi Kavya.. I'm able to create Sentinel Automation Contributor on serviceprincipal on resource group level  but not on Azure Security Insights. How to fetch the objectId of AzureSecurityInsights app using terraform ?